# PHP Parameters ignored in Gmail Proxy email

Tags: php, email, parameters, proxy, gmail

I am sending a PHP image through email that uses parameters to determine the image to display. This image displays in every email client except Gmail. The reason for this is due to the Google User Content Proxy, which wraps around the link and shows the php file while ignoring the parameters attached to it.

I seem to have the same problem as this question,
[Problems with tracking pixels and Gmail proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38226003/problems-with-tracking-pixels-and-gmail-proxy). Their solution was the following:

> I resolved it using https://www.example.com/tracking.php/order_id=1
>   instead and then on the tracking.php I didn't use $_GET but
>   $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] and parsed the /order_id= String.

The problem is I don't understand how to do this.

When I visit the file URL for `test.php?par=1`, I am able to pull par using $_GET. If I switch the file URL to `test.php/par=1`, I receive a 404 error.

How do I use `/par=1` as my parameter while still accessing test.php first so I can pull the whole url using $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`test.php?par=1` is a script named `test.php` with a query string key of `par` and value `1`.

If you do not have [pathinfo](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#acceptpathinfo) enabled, then `test.php/par=1` is a DIRECTORY name `test.php`, and a non-existent file in that directory named `par=1`.

Note that PHP won't parse pathinfo data into $_GET. Only actual `?key=val`-type query values are processed for that. You'll have to dig out `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` and parse it yourself.

Comment: Thank you!! Pathinfo was what I had to enable.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working and tested for Gmail. My php image successfully shows up!

I edited my `test.php` file from this:

**test.php?val=1**

```
$value = $_GET['val'];
```

To this:

**test.php/val=1**

```
$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$path = substr($uri, strpos($uri, "val="));
$delim = 'alv=';
$tok = strtok($path, $delim);

$tokens = array();
while ($tok !== false) {
    array_push($tokens, $tok);
    $tok = strtok($delim);
}
$value = $tokens[0];
```